# How to choose several characters in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to realize it:

> "Calculate the number of people who live in a zip code in the US where
>   the city starts with one of the following characthers: B, D, O, G, N
>   or M ."

So, writing and using aggregation pipeline like:

```
 db.zips.aggregate( { $project :{digits : {$substr : [ "$city", 0, 1] }, pop : 1, city : "$city", zip : "$_id", state : 1}},{ $match :{ digits : /\M/ } },{ $group :{_id : null, pop : { $sum : "$pop"}}})
```

Successfully getting the result just with **M** digit, but I want to add more: B, D, O, G, N

```
{ "_id" : null, "pop" : 19499064 }
```

Trying to add other digits, something like:

```
db.zips.aggregate( { $project :{digits : {$substr : [ "$city", 0, 1] }, pop : 1, city : "$city", zip : "$_id", state : 1}},{ $match :{ digits :  /\M/, /\B/, /\D/, /\O/,/\G/,/\N/ } },{ $group :{_id : null, pop : { $sum : "$pop"}}})
```

And getting the error:

```
2018-07-03T20:47:07.273+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):1:151
```

**P.S.** I know about :

```
{ $match:  { city: { $in: [ /^b.*/i, /^d.*/i, /^o.*/i, /^g.*/i, /^n.*/i, /^m.*/i ] } } }
```

But how can I present the digits correctly in first variant with format above? Like `/\M/` with several digits.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First of all it's a wrong regexp. It must be `/[MBDOGN]/`. In fact you don't need regexps at all. They are expensive. You already extracted the first character, so direct comparison is enough: `digits: {$in: ['M', 'B', 'D', 'O', 'G', 'N']}`

Comment: @AlexBlex, thanks for response and correction. But why regular expressions are expencive?

Comment: They are too powerful. You don't employ Schumacher to deliver you pizza.